# От закрывающих кавычек до следующего слова пробел ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, пробелы

От закрывающих кавычек до следующего слова пробел ставится?

Comment: Не расшифровал - можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно, между закрывающими кавычками и следующим словом пробел необходим (как между обычными, не "закавыченными" словами).

*Отель **«Сентрал» до** недавнего времени был одной из достопримечательностей Эдинбурга, но пять лет назад он сгорел дотла* (И. Рэнкин).
*Их веселое «Добрый **день!» звоном** отдалось у него в ушах* (К. Аткинсон).
 *Еще 20 лет назад понятие **«планета» казалось** простым и ясным.*

Пробел ставится и в том случае, если после слова в кавычках идут скобки:
«Волга», «Ока», «Таврия» (автомобили), «Руслан» (самолет), «Минск» (холодильник); исключения: «жигули», «мерседес» (автомобили).

http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=33#pp33